# Regular expression to replace everything between the html tags <table> and </table>?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've got some html string and I'd like to use `preg_replace` to replace everything between

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

...and...

```
</table>
```

Any thoughts?

```
"/<table border=\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/table>/ims"
```

does not work for me :(

Comment: Using regexes could work but only if your table does not contain any nested tables.

Comment: Or the literal text `</table>`, for instance in a comment. And tags can contain whitespace, so `</ table >` is perfectly valid, but won't get caught by the regex. And in your example, `border` doesn't have to be the first attribute. And...

Comment: dup of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little correction is needed:

```
$html = preg_replace("'([<]table border=[^>]*[>]).*?([<]/table[>])'ims", "\\1".$your_stuff."\\2", $html);
```

Note: I used to put `<` and `>` characters in square brackets, just a habit.

Answer (score 0):

Lookarounds should help you

```
(?<=<table).*(?=</table>)
```

See the [results](http://regexr.com?31i9m) here.

**PS**: If you want to ignore spaces at places, throw in `\s` wherever required.